# How can I add my application in loginwindow.plist Programatically in MAcOs

Tags: macos, authentication

I want my application to run as soon as user login.
For this I need the modify the /Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist.
Manually I can do this using Plist Editor but I want to do this in my code.
How can I do this Programatically using C/C++

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not do this by editing loginwindow.plist. Use the LSSharedFileList API, which is in the Launch Services framework within the Core Services umbrella framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a launchd job instead.